# How to compare two tables of different databases and create a new table from their match?(MySql Query)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have two different databases `a_db` and `b_db`.

there are two tables in `a_db`, `table_a` and `table_b`

Columns of table_a are :

`id, part_number, price, qty`

also, table in `b_db` is `table_c`

Columns of table_c are:

`id, part_number, place, delivery`

Now I want to create a match of `part_number` column between `table_a` and `table_c`  and store the rows of `table_a` that matches with `table_c` and store in `table_b`

Any idea in the python to do this.

```
conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="",
  user="",
  password="",
  database="a_db"
)

conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="",
  user="",
  password="",
  database="b_db"
)

cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

cursor1.executemany ( """
SQL query
"""  )
```

Since I have to execute from cursor1. What will be the SQL query in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do the data manipulation within you python script, you could query both table_a and table_c separately, and store their respective part_number records in your script.  You could then convert these lists of part_numbers to sets, and take their intersection.  This is basically the same as a sql inner join, in that it will return only the part_numbers that exist in both tables.

You could then use this list of common part_numbers to query table_a, and select the results into table_b.

Alternatively, this could be done using an actual sql join, but I don't have an answer on the correct way to join across db's in mysql offhand.  If others weigh in, I would be interested to see how this is done as well.